# Supabase insert fails due to RLS even through INSERT works in postgres console

Tags: postgresql, supabase

I am implementing an authentication framework within supabase that supports multiple roles with various permissions and therefore create multiple policies for different scenarios.

All my policies are covered with a set of integration tests to ensure continuity.

A particular issue that I'm facing is that INSERT statement from supabase JS API fails due to row-level validation even through the same INSERT works as the SQL statement in Posgres console.

---

I have a table `clients` roughly defined as

```sql
CREATE TABLE clients (
  id serial primary key,
  name varchar
);

ALTER TABLE clients ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;

CREATE POLICY "Allow client_admin to create new record if none exist" ON clients
    FOR INSERT TO authenticated
    WITH CHECK (
        auth.is_user_in_group(auth.uid(), 'client_admin')
        AND auth.client_ids() IS NULL
    );
```

My test looks like the following

```js
// Given
const newUser = await createUser({
  email: 'new_client+test@example.com',
})
await logInAs(newUser)

// When
const { data, error } = await anonClient
  .from('clients')
  .insert([generateClient({}).record])
```

NOTE: `generateClient(...)` function only generates an object with random data and does not do any inserts.

That insert statement fails with

```
{"code": "42501", "details": null, "hint": null, "message": "new row violates row-level security policy for table \"clients\""}
```

Even through if I open a console in DataGrip and do

```sql
SET "request.jwt.claim.sub" TO '6aab88c8-6cc9-48fa-a90a-d45bfdc4a055';
SET ROLE authenticated;

INSERT INTO clients(name) VALUES (gen_random_uuid());
INSERT INTO clients(name) VALUES (gen_random_uuid());
```

The first insert works, whereas the 2nd fails as expected.

To make this experiment clean, I even tried the following policy

```sql
CREATE POLICY "Allow client_admin to create new record if none exist" ON clients
    FOR INSERT TO authenticated
    WITH CHECK (
      true
    );
```

I even tried removing all other policies to make sure they do not interfere somehow.

Any ideas about where I could have made a mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it often happens, almost immediately after posting on SO I figured out the answer.

I've been reading SQL query log and found that supabase would also attempt to SELECT the data immediately after insert.

Roughly looks like

```sql
INSERT INTO clients(name) VALUES (gen_random_uuid()) RETURNING clients.*;
```

I have a trigger that inserts a new record to the `client_users` table and affects SELECT Policy.

Apparently what happens here is that:

```
TRANSACTION STARTS
INSERT to clients
RETURNING clients.* <--- FAILS RLS AND REVERTS TRANSACTION
INSERT to client_users <--- Should let SELECT RLS work, but fails due to order of operations
```

For those who have faced the same issue, there seem to be two options:

- Configure SELECT Policy
- Do supabase insert that does not return any information

```
const { data, error } = await anonClient
  .from('clients')
  .insert(generateClient({}).record, {
    returning: 'minimal',
  })
```